# Why are some flags is still active?

Tags: discussion

There are some flags that I have raised in the past that are still active, and some are were raised more than a year ago.  Why moderators haven't not reviewed them yet?

Comment: Got 1 pass the 1 year mark and one nearing (on the 25 this month), bet some people have older ones.

Comment: @iStimple I don't think original question will review my flags BTW.

Comment: The oldest flags currently in the moderator queue are from yesterday, so any older than that are in the close review queue.